# how to search a hash using the values and return the corresponding key upon success in perl

Tags: perl, hashtable

I am looking for search implementation on hash using perl. I have following data in my hash

```
%hash = {0 => "Hello", 1=> "world"}.
```

Now i want to search the hash using the values (means world and hello) and return corresponding key.

Example: I want to search for world and the result should be 1

Comment: first of all,change the `{` `}` brackets to `(` `)`.`{` `}` will return a anonymous hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate of the keys of the hash with a `for ( keys %hash ) ...` statement and check the values as you go. If you find what you are looking for, return

```
my $hash = { 0 => "World", 1 => "Hello" };

for ( keys %$hash ) {
    my $val = $hash->{$_};
    return $_ if $val eq 'World'; # or whatever you are looking for
}
```

another option would be to use `while ( ... each ... )`

```
my $hash = { 0 => "World", 1 => "Hello" };

while (($key, $val) = each %$hash) {
    return $key if $val eq 'World'; # or whatever you are looking for
}
```

the use of `{ }` literal creates a hash reference and not a hash

```
$h = { a => 'b', c => 'd' };
```

to create a literal hash you use `( )`

```
%h = ( a => 'b', c => 'd' );
```

execution of `while ... each` on hashref

```
$h = { a => 'b', c => 'd' };
print "$k :: $v\n" while (($k, $v) = each %$h );  

c :: d
a :: b
```

Comment: I tried using each keyword, but the value is not getting returned/ printed.

Comment: i have initialised hash as my %hash. Could this be the culprit

Answer (score 2):

If:

1. The hash isn't very large, and
2. The values are unique

You can simply create a lookup hash with [`reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html):

```
my %lookup = reverse %hash;
my $key = $lookup{'world'}; # key from %hash or undef
```

Comment: herp, I was thinking *after* the reverse; fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (0 => "Hello", 1=> "world");
my $val = 'world';

my @keys = grep { $hash{$_} eq $val } keys %hash;

print "Keys: ", join(", ", @keys), "\n";
```

This will return all keys i.e. If the value is same for multiple keys.